# Change outgoing IP on .NET WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control, ip-address

I have a system which has multiple internet IP addresses and there is a requirement for a WebBrowserControl to be able to load balance across all of them.  Does anyone know how to change the outbound IP address when a WebBrowser control makes requests?

Unfortunately I can't use WebRequests - it has to be a browser control based solution.

Comment: You can tell the system what interface to use for outbound connections based on destination IP.  I forget the windows command - look up route tables.

Comment: Destination IP is not predictable - the destination is load balanced too.  Really needs to be controlled on a per request basis via code.

Comment: That's not how the system works.  The best you can do is shut down the interfaces you do not want to use - cycling a single interface on for each request.  Unfortunately that would limit your outbound connections to one at a time - given your stated restrictions.

Comment: The only way I can think of getting this to work is to create a local proxy service that will do the load balancing for you, allowing you to use the WebBrowser control.